# Как сохранить картинку, при получении готового изображения

Tags: php, файлы, изображения

Мне нужно сохранить картинку, получаю я её в следующем виде:

```
����JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality =85
��C !"$"$��C��X�"��
```

это только первые 2 строчки, на самом деле там их очень много, примерно то же самое как картинка открытая в notepad, в таком виде я её получаю из 1С.

Вопрос, как её сохранить в нужную папку?

Comment: как вы её получаете? Где код?

Comment: получаю вызовом функции ПолучитьИзображение с параметром id, из 1С, код ничего не даст

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запишите всё полученное содержимое в файл и сохраните его с разрешением jpg

```
$file = "test.jpg";
$data_from_c1 ='dfg';
$fle = fopen($file, 'w+');
fwrite($fle, 'яЩя');
fwrite($fle, $data_from_c1);
fclose($fle);
```

Comment: отлично, все работает, но теперь возникла другая проблема, в записаном через php файле нехватает вначале 3 символа. Если открыть через блокнот рабочая картинка начинается с "яЩя",а в файле записаном через php этого нет, если добавить вручную, тогда картинка нормально открывается, а если через php дописать в начало эти символы, он сохраняет в формате UTF-8 без BOM. Как быть в таком случае? Можно ли как-то записать HEX этих символов в начало файла, и чтобы он сохранился в ANCII?

Comment: записывайте что угодно. Код дополнил. Запись последовательная. Т.е. каждый новый вызов функции `frite()` допишет к уже записанному в файл.

Comment: в hex можно преобразовать функцией, коих море. Например - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537895/php-string-to-hex

Comment: А acii или нет - нужна марка в начале тексата, которая отвечает за кодировку. яЩя мозмоно и есть эта метка. Например для utf8 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12215021/6004176

Comment: нет, он все равно сохраняет файл в UTF-8 без BOM(

Comment: а какая собственно для картинки разница?

Comment: Давайте начнём с того, что не яЩя, а яШя. А у меня, например, и того больше - https://i.imgur.com/K930Nwj.png

Comment: откройте через Notepad++ лучше всего

Comment: ну я эти символы скопировал из notepad++, вы правы, там не Щ, а Ш, но это не влияет, так как он все равно сохраняет в UTF-8 без BOM, а из за того, что он сохраняет не в ANSI содержимое полностью другое, и при попытки конвертировать в ANSI он его конвертирует криво

Comment: можно ли как-то задать кодировку для файла?

Comment: Попробуйте вот так - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622090/open-save-file-in-ascii-format Создайте вручную пустой файл с нужной кодировкой и т.п. Получите его содержимое, допишите нужное и сохраните. Ещё вариант - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386371/php-how-to-save-text-file-with-ansi-encoding. Гуглите. Это выходит за рамки вопроса.